# Python program Attribute:Error module 'reader' has no attribute 'Reader'

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I'm trying to test run my program in C:\reader\compressed\ where I have created two test files 'test.gzip' and 'test.bz2' but when I go run the Reader class I get that the module reader has no attribute 'Reader'.

I'm opening python to "import reader" then "r = reader.Reader('test.bz2')"
Directory looks like: 
[image]
[image]

I can import all the modules I've created.

```
import reader
import reader.compressed
import reader.compressed.gzipped
import reader.compressed.bzipped
```

Here is my reader.py:

```
import os

from reader.compressed import gzipped, bzipped

extension_map = {
    '.bz2': bzipped.opener, 
    '.gz': gzipped.opener,
}

class Reader:
def __init__(self, filename):
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    opener = extension_map.get(extension, open)
    self.f = opener(filename, 'rt')

    def close(self):
        self.f.close()

    def read(self):
        return self.f.read()
```

I've checked my modules to see that they are there along with the new files to test that are supposed to return the messages.

```
>>> import reader
>>> r= reader.reader.Reader('test.gz')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'reader' has no attribute 'reader'

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Develop\Python\reader\__init__.py", line 13, in 
 __init__
 self.f = opener(filename, 'rt') 
 File"C:\Python\Python36\lib\gzip.py", line 53, in open
binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
File  
 "C:\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\gzip.py", line 163, in 
 __init__
fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 
'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'test.gz'
```

Comment: How are you running the Reader class?

Comment: I don't fully understand your file and module layout, but I'd guess there's a conflict between your `reader.py` file (defining a `reader` module) and the `C:\reader` folder that defines a `reader` package (with the `compressed` subpackage in it).

Comment: @Blckknght I added the file view.

Comment: @PaulaThomas I have the command above.  I "import reader" then "r= reader.Reader('test.gzip')"

Comment: But where is reader.compressed coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reader` class is not defined in a top-level `reader` module. Rather, it's defined in `reader.reader`, since the top level `reader` is a package.

If your current code that's causing the error is:

```
import reader
r= reader.Reader('test.gzip')
```

You need to change it to use `reader.reader` instead of just `reader`:

```
import reader.reader
r = reader.reader.Reader('test.gzip')
```

Or alternatively, you could move the contents of `reader/reader.py` into `reader/__init__.py`, since the latter file is where the contents of the `reader` package are defined. Or you could split the difference, and keep the `reader.py` file while still making the class available at package level, using something like this in `__init__.py` (note I've not tested this, there are some weird corner cases with relative imports from `__init__.py` files):

```
from .reader import Reader
```

Comment: I've already tried both of those while troubleshooting to still get the problem.

Comment: Please show the code you tried and the full traceback of the exception you get when you run it. If you do have a `reader.Reader` class, or you actually try to use `reader.reader.Reader`, you should at least be getting a different error, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your file name should not be same as a standard module name. So, rename `reader.py` to `reader1.py` or so.

Comment: There is no standard library module named `reader` (at least, not at the top level).

Comment: @Blckknght I added the Traceback.